# Displaying the users data in ionic 3 from Firebase

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I  have a problem with the `.val()` property. On this line:

`this.userProfile = profile.val();`

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthService } from "../../providers/auth/auth.service";
import { DataService } from "../../providers/data/data.service";
import { User } from 'firebase/app'
import { Profile } from "../../models/profile/profile.interface";
import jQuery from "jquery";
import { getQueryValue } from "@angular/core/src/view/query";
import { USER_LIST } from "../../mocks/profiles/profile";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-profile-view',
    templateUrl: 'profile-view.component.html'
})
export class ProfileViewComponent implements OnInit {
    userProfile: Profile;         

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.auth.getAuthenticatedUser().subscribe((user: User) => {
            this.data.getProfile(user).valueChanges().subscribe(profile => {
                this.userProfile = <Profile>profile.val(); //here is the problem
            })
        })
    }
}
```

And this is the profile-interface:

```js
export interface Profile {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    avatar: string;
    email: string;
    dateOfBirth: Date;
}
```

And this is profile.ts from /mocks

```js
import { Profile } from '../../models/profile/profile.interface';

const userList: Profile[] = [
    {firstName: 'ahmed', lastName: 'hallaq', email: 'a.m.hq@hotmail.com', avatar: 'assets/img/avatar.png', dateOfBirth: new Date() },
    {firstName: 'ahmed', lastName: 'hallaq', email: 'a.m.hq@hotmail.com', avatar: 'assets/img/avatar.png', dateOfBirth: new Date() },
    {firstName: 'ahmed', lastName: 'hallaq', email: 'a.m.hq@hotmail.com', avatar: 'assets/img/avatar.png', dateOfBirth: new Date() },
    {firstName: 'ahmed', lastName: 'hallaq', email: 'a.m.hq@hotmail.com', avatar: 'assets/img/avatar.png', dateOfBirth: new Date() },
];

export const USER_LIST = userList;
```

This is from the html file I want it to show the first name from the database:

```html
<ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>First Name</ion-label>
    <ion-input [value]="userProfile.firstNAme" [readonly]="true"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

When I do ionic serve, it gives me [[profile.val is not a function]]

How can I get the users information in the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which `val` function are you expecting it to execute on a profile object of Type `Profile` interface?

Because it doesn't find any for `Profile` type of object , it can't execute it and is reporting an error. Add the `val` function and it will stop reporting.

Comment: How can i add the val method in profile object? Im beginner

Comment: even i am a beginner, but i have created classes in place of interfaces, and defined the model properties and behaviors inside of it, by the way, what is that which you are expecting val to perform on that object ?

Comment: I want the val to get the data from profile like firstName and date of birth to show it in the profile page

Comment: I don't think you need any val function there , if you have got a profile object set to userProfile , then you can access the properties of it in html the way you are already doing it

Comment: I do it the same without val function and nothing shows

Comment: try to see the value of userProfile using console statement , whether its getting populated as expected or not, and please upload your code somewhere if possible that would be a great help...

Comment: I can give you my ionic project to see the problem

Comment: sure, i can have a look and see if i can figure out the issue. you can upload  a sample on stackblitz

Comment: i put the src file